Do the FAA provide help on airworthiness of ultralights?
The answer to the question Can my plane get off the ground? has the comment:

I'm going to get it checked by the faa

Part 103 for Ultralights says that:

(a) Any person operating an ultralight vehicle under this part shall,
upon request, allow the Administrator, or his designee, to inspect the
vehicle to determine the applicability of this part. (b) The pilot or
operator of an ultralight vehicle must, upon request of the
Administrator, furnish satisfactory evidence that the vehicle is
subject only to the provisions of this part.

but also that

(a) Notwithstanding any other section pertaining to certification of
aircraft or their parts or equipment, ultralight vehicles and their
component parts and equipment are not required to meet the
airworthiness certification standards specified for aircraft or to
have certificates of airworthiness. (b) Notwithstanding any other
section pertaining to airman certification, operators of ultralight
vehicles are not required to meet any aeronautical knowledge, age, or
experience requirements to operate those vehicles or to have airman or
medical certificates.

That doesn't sound like the sort of airworthiness consultancy that the comment implies.  In the UK you could ask the British Microlight Aircraft Association to look over your design.  Do the FAA provide that sort of service?

The BMAA is a very different kind of organization from the FAA.

@DJClayworth  Exactly, that's why I mentioned it.

"get it checked" is more likely to mean have it inspected vs "consultancy" IMHO.


(a) Any person operating an ultralight vehicle under this part shall, upon request, allow the Administrator, or his designee, to inspect the vehicle to determine the applicability of this part. (b) The pilot or operator of an ultralight vehicle must, upon request of the Administrator, furnish satisfactory evidence that the vehicle is subject only to the provisions of this part.

This inspection is limited to checking that an ultralight is in fact an ultralight. For a powered ultralight, this means no more than 254 pounds empty, single seat, no more than 5 gallons of fuel capacity, etc. Once it's determined to be a legal ultralight, the FAA's interest in its airworthiness (or lack thereof) ends.

The FAA doesn't want to know about your legal ultralight. There's no "FAA inspection" of them not are they required to be registered or issued an airworthiness certificate.
Illegal ultralights, especially ones that can carry a passenger, will get their attention and fines issued.
Good luck.
